# Xcode plugin for selecting font?

Tags: xcode, cocoa, xcode5, nsfont, nsfontpanel

Is there some handy Xcode plugin allowing us to select fonts the way [ColorSense](https://github.com/omz/ColorSense-for-Xcode) allows us to conveniently work with colors in code?

Something that would e.g. display a font dialog and return the appropriate `NSFont` initializer call as text in the file currently open in the editor?